# Create Windows CA Certificate Template from Command line

Tags: windows, ad-certificate-services

As part of installing our product, we are generally required to setup AD and CA services. I found a way to install the CA from the command line: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff849263(v=ws.10).aspx . But is there a way to generate Certificate templates from the command line as well?

Comment: Follow the scripts below for how to do what you need:

https://powershell.org/forums/topic/certificate-templates-add-catemplate-problems/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/347acc93-8352-4535-ab1a-23ebd49eea22/duplicate-certificate-template-edit-and-publish-it?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Do not follow the scripts above.

Comment: I hadn't gotten around to trying them yet. Is there any reason not to do so? The technet article looks like what I was hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

Certificate Template creation is supported via Certificate Templates MMC snap-in only. There are no supported command-line tools that would do that.